# python 3.6 appending list created duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.6

My program will calculate a final grade, I believe thats all correct up until Im creating multiple entries. when i enter 'y' to enter another student the second student copies into the first students list then dulplicates itself resulting in a copy and not my first original entry. so instead of having mike, jim, and mary its mary, mary, and mary.

```
#This program will calculate a classes final grades.

def get_grades():

    print("\nEnter grades for assignments 1-5 (0-20 PT scale)")

    assignment1 = eval(input("\nEnter assignment 1 grade: "))
    assignment2 = eval(input("Enter     ''     2 grade: "))
    assignment3 = eval(input("Enter     ''     3 grade: "))
    assignment4 = eval(input("Enter     ''     4 grade: "))
    assignment5 = eval(input("Enter     ''     5 grade: "))

    total = (assignment1 + assignment2 + assignment3 + assignment4 + assignment5)

    print("\nEnter the Midterm and Final exam grades (0-100 PT scale))")
    midterm = eval(input("\nMidterm grade: "))
    final = eval(input("Final grade: "))

    exam_avg = (final + midterm)/2

    print("\nEnter the participation grade (0-10 PT scale)")
    participation = int(input("Participation: "))

    final_grade = (total*0.45) + (exam_avg*0.45) + participation

    return final_grade

def determine_let_grade(final_grade):

    if final_grade > 100 or final_grade < 0:
        return "ERROR!"

    elif final_grade <= 100 and final_grade > 90:
        return "A"

    elif final_grade <= 89 and final_grade > 80:
        return "B"

    elif final_grade <= 79 and final_grade > 70:
        return "C"

    elif final_grade <= 69 and final_grade > 60:
        return "D"

    elif final_grade <= 59:
        return "F"   

def main():

    print("This program will calculate your students final grades.")

    studentList = []
    another_student = "y" 

    while another_student == 'y':
        name = input("\nEnter the student's name: ")
        net_id = int(input("Enter the student's Identification number: ")) 
        fnl_grade = get_grades()
        let_grade = determine_let_grade(fnl_grade)
        studentList.append([name, net_id, fnl_grade, let_grade])
        another_student = input("\nEnter y or n to add another student: ")

    for student in range(len(studentList)):
        print("\nStudent Name:", name.title() ,"\nStudent-ID:", net_id ,"\nFinal Grade:",fnl_grade ,"\nLetter Grade:", let_grade)
        print()
    input ("Please press Enter to quit the program")
main()
```

Comment: in your print loop you're printing the last values printed, not the values of the list...

Comment: `for student in range(len(studentList)):` complicates this further since `student` then becomes an integer with which to index your list, which isn't very intuitive. I would change to `for student in studentList:` and the first part of your `print` would be `print("\nStudent Name:", student[0] ,"\nStudent-ID:", student[1] ,...")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `name`, `net_id`, `fnl_grade`, and `let_grade` in the `while` loop. When you exit the loop, these variable keep the value of the last iteration. You just print these variables in the following for loop without setting them. You probably want to use following for condition:

```
  for name, net_id, fnl_grade, let_grade in studentList:
      print("\nStudent Name:", name.title() ,"\nStudent-ID:", net_id ,"\nFinal Grade:",fnl_grade ,"\nLetter Grade:", let_grade)
      print()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in your list, it's in you for loop.

Instead of using the `name`, `net_id`, `fnl_grade` and `let_grade` variable you need to use the student you are looping on. Also, since `studentList` is a list, you can simply loop on it

```
for student in studentList:
    print("\nStudent Name:", student[0] ,"\nStudent-ID:", student[1] ,"\nFinal Grade:",student[2] ,"\nLetter Grade:", student[3])
```